# How to send variable to policy from the view using @can in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using the `@can` of policy in a view to show a button if the policy return true, And i want to send the variable `$offer` to the policy the problem here is that the variable `$offer` is not in the normal case because it's in a foreach loop of another varible, I will explain more:

Their is a foreach that loop a messages and every message has role the message can be a message sent from the user or admin and also can be an offer from the admin and here things start to be complicated by using the array inside array and in the final i have to send the array varible to the policy

I tried to send the variable `$offer[($message->content - 1)]` like that and it's not working.

I tried also to replace the `@can` by `@if($offer[($message->content - 1)]->the_status != 'paid')` And it works but i need a policy because i will add others conditions

This is the can:

```
@can('accept', $offer[($message->content - 1)])
    <button></button>
    @include("layouts.modals.accept_offer")
@else
    Paid
@endcan
```

The policy code is:

```
public function accept(User $user, Payments_offer $offer)
{
    if($offer->the_status == 'paid')
    {
        return false;
    }
        return $user->id == $offer->user_id;
}
```

It work as like sending the class and not a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you described, the following should work.

```
// View

@can('accept', $offer[id])
    <button></button>
    @include("layouts.modals.accept_offer")
@else
    Paid
@endcan

// Policy

public function accept(User $user, Payments_offer $offer)
{
    if($offer->the_status == 'paid')
    {
        return false;
    }
        return $user->id == $offer->user_id;
}
```

Comment: $offer variable is an array that have a lot of offers

Comment: What i mean is when doing $offer[1]->id it give us an ID and when we do $offer[2]->id it will give us another ID

Comment: @عليلواحمد is it an array of objects or an array of arrays?

Comment: $offer   = Payments_offer::where('conversation_id', '=', $conversation->id)->get();

Comment: As you see it's (get) and so it's array inside array first array is for sql rows and the second is for the columns (id, user_id..)

Comment: And as you see in the code $offer[($message->content - 1)]

Comment: it's just because i saved the number of the offer in the message table in the content column

Comment: I have an idea i can send the $offer variable as you said but i must send the number also ($message->content) How can i do it ?

Comment: @عليلواحمد simply sending $offer[id] should be enough. What error message do you get?

Comment: it does not work, Even i forced return false in the policy it show the button

Comment: @عليلواحمد is the policy registered in `AuthServiceProvider` ? Have you tested whether the policy code actually gets executed?

Comment: I am sorry for that it was the function before i commented it's work fine now, Oh sheets happen

Comment: @عليلواحمد happens all the time :)